# WPF Binding color in ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm learning WPF and in my application I want to use accent color that is defined by user. All my styles are defined in `Style.xaml` which is a `ResourceDictionary`. What I want to achieve is this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namespace"
    x:Class="Namespace.Style"
    x:ClassModifier="public">

    <Color x:Key="AccentColor" 
        A="{Binding Accent.A}"
        R="{Binding Accent.R}"
        G="{Binding Accent.G}"
        B="{Binding Accent.B}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentBrush" Color="{Binding AccentColor}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in `Style.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace Namespace
{
    public partial class Style : ResourceDictionary
    {
        // this color can be changed later
        public Color Accent { get; set; }

        public Style()
        {
            Accent = Color.FromRgb(0x13, 0xaf, 0xf0);

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Code above gives error:

```
'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'A' property of type 'Color'. 
 A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'
```

What are other ways (preferably not too complex, but also flexible) to implement this feature to let user define his own accent color for application's theme?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against "getting a colour from code behind.

Often you want a brush but sometimes a colour.
Here's how I usually define these:

```
<Color x:Key="PaleBlue">#44A7F7</Color>
<Color x:Key="PaleRed">#F75B71</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PaleBlueBrush" Color="{StaticResource PaleBlue}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PaleRedBrush" Color="{StaticResource PaleRed}"/>
```

These go in a resourcedictionary which is merged in app.xaml so they have scope for the entire app.

If I wish to change a theme I define another resource dictionary for ( say ) Dark Theme and another for Blue Theme... and so on.

To change themes I merge the appropriate resource dictionary into application.current.resources and they then replace the original.
You need to use DynamicResource to reference these if you want them to change immediately but often a theme change is an unusual thing and "just" totally reloading your window is acceptable.

You can replace one of those in code if you really wanted to.

Application.Current.Resources["PaleRedBrush"] = // some new solidcolorbrush.

A lot of things in a resourcedictionary are frozen ( there's a Freeze() method ) and you can't change them.
I never tried to implement exactly what you're doing there but I think it might be problematic.

You could alternatively use a bridging static dependency object or class which implements inotifypropertychanged. One candidate would involve a observabledictionary as property in a static. That'd allow you to bind to brush by string as name. http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/ 
Not tried that neither.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything in the Styles.xaml.cs. Create a Styles.xaml ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColor" Color="#FFFFFF" />
</<ResourceDictionary>
```

To use this color in the other xaml files, you will have to declare it inside the merged dictionary tag along with it's path:

```
<Window>
<Window.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary x:Uid="ResourceDictionary_1">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</Window.Resources>
<TextBlock Background="{StaticResource AccentColor}"/>
</Window>
```

You can use it the way I used to apply the TextBlock background.
You will have to provide the path of your Styles.xaml in the Source tag of ResourceDictionary.

Comment: The problem is I don't want Color to be hardcoded like `"#FFFFFF"`. I should be get from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit). The demo comes with a style switch implementation. You can take a look at the example to see how it works, it's all open source.

Comment: That's cool, really. I'll use this library. But right now I'm trying to understand basics of WPF and I want to find out how to do this with pure WPF. As I said, I don't want too complex solution. If this is not possible to do in WPF, fine, I'll make dozens of preset styles with different colors. I just want it to be simple and flexible at once.

Comment: See Raviraj Palvankar's answer. Otherwise if you don't want to define a style with dictionaries you can use bindings. The thing with your code is that you don't have a datacontext. What is "Accent" that you are trying to bind to? Wpf doesn't know. The error you are getting is explained as follows: Color is a bindable property but Color.r/g/b is not.

Comment: @dovaogedot Maybe this will help with styling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating after learning this you can learn how to use dictionaries and merged dictionaries to make the "active style" switchable.